Fatal error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in /var/www/html/bootstrap/app.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/public/index.php(13): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/bootstrap/app.php on line 7
I've run my docker container and done composer install. I've also done composer install outside of my docker container. I've deleted the composer.lock file and vendor folder and run composer install.
This is a laravel application using nginx to serve the application.
I've also tried doing stuff like composer install --no-scripts.
bootstrap/app.php:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

